# How to wake up a FreeRtos task from a high priority ISR?

Tags: stm32, freertos, isr

Using:

- Stm32F10x, F2xx, F4xx
- FreeRtos 8.1.1
- gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q2

I have an ISR which must run with high interrupt priority, so that's forbidden to call FreeRtos Api from within this ISR (see [here](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html) and [here](http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#kernel_priority)).

In some cases these ISR detects conditions, for which a sleeping FreeRtos task should be waked up with at least possible latency.

Normally (if the ISR was allowed to call FreeRtos Api because of enough low priority) I would use a queue or semaphore to solve this.

But how to realize that with a high priority ISR?

My current interims approach is like this (briefly outlined):

```
volatile int flag = 0;

void XYZ_IRQHandler() {
    if (someCondition)
        flag = 1
}

void FreeRtosTaskFunction(void* parameters) {
    for (;;) {
        if (flag == 1)
            doSomething();
        vTaskDelay(1);  // sleep 10ms (tick frequency is 100Hz)
    }
}
```

But this approach has the disadvantages:

- Latency (from setting the flag in ISR until task wakeup) to is up to 1 FreeRtos tick.
- Need to poll the flag (waste of cpu cycles).

Any suggestions to solve this in a better way, especially with less latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea, although not tested seems like it should work.

I am assuming that your ISR is a high priority because it needs an extremely low latency to do something unaffected by other interrupts (i.e., take a measurement at an exact time), and the task should be done quickly, but isn't quite as critical (i.e., transmit or display the value).

In your high-priority ISR, perform the timing-critical function, and then trigger a low-priority internal interrupt.

When the high-priority ISR is complete, (as well as any others pending), the low-priority ISR will be called. This can then call the FreeRTOS API and initiate the task with no further delay.

Comment: Any idea / link how to trigger a internal interrupt?

Comment: Ok, found `EXTI_GenerateSWInterrupt()` within the st-lib. Unfortulately, it needs to waste a EXTI Line and also an irq channel. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: [Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/discussion/382005/thread/140cde98/#694c) is another approach without the use of EXTI, but because of using a FreeRtos trace macro, it's a bit too hacky for my project. I'd now applied the EXTI based solution in combination with a FreeRtos semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use FreeRTOS [Task notification](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notifications.html).

Your task will pend, then resume/awaken right away upon the ISR event.

Comment: FreeRtos Task Notification (introduced with FreeRtos 8.2) is a nice alternative to a semaphore. But note that it's also not allowed to call that api from a ISR with high interrupt priority.